# what's the quickest way to get the submap of a map

Tags: java

I have a map, I am wondering if there is a way to get some submap according to some condition. Any useful library?

Comment: can you give an example of a condition?

Comment: Does the submap need to be backed by the original (i.e. do you want updates to be visible in both)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) the [`Maps`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html) class contains three different filtering methods, depending on whether you want to filter by key, value, or both.

Comment: Note Guava Maps filter methods are not optimized for performance, because they maintain a live view and filter by a predicate, causing methods like size() and contains to have performance O(n). The javadoc gives some warning for such cases and suggests to materialize the view.

Comment: If the condition is something like `keyCollection.contains(key)`, then it is much more efficient to instead iterate over the keyCollection and call `map.get()` for each key.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a [NavigableMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) will do what you want, depending on what the condition is.  It is very fast `O(log n)` whereas most filters are `O(n)`.  It can take the sub map of key less than, greater than or between two keys.